# Kubernetes apply service but endpoints is none

Tags: docker, kubernetes

When I tried to apply a service to pod, endpoint is always none. Could someone know any root cause? I also check if selector match to what is defined in the deployment.yaml. Belows are the deployment, service file that I used. I also attached the service describe.

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gethnode
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    app: gethnode
    env: dev1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gethnode
      env: dev1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gethnode
        env: dev1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gethnode
        image: myserver.th/bc/gethnode:1.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8550
        env:
        - name: TZ
          value: Asis/Bangkok
        tty: true
        stdin: true
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 512Mi
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred-harbor
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gethnode
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    app: gethnode
    env: dev1
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    port: 8550
    targetPort: 8550
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: gethnode
    env: dev1
```

kubectl describe svc

```
Name:              gethnode
Namespace:         mynamespace
Labels:            app=gethnode
                   env=dev1
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"gethnode","env":"dev1"},"name":"gethnode","namespace":"c...
Selector:          app=gethnode,env=dev1
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                192.97.37.19
Port:              tcp  8550/TCP
TargetPort:        8550/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

kubectl get pods -n mynamespace --show-labels

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE    LABELS
console-bctest-6bff897bf4-xmch8   1/1     Running            0          6d3h   app=bctest,env=dev1,pod-template-hash=6bff897bf4
console-dev1-595c47c678-s5mzz     1/1     Running            0          20d    app=console,env=dev1,pod-template-hash=595c47c678
gethnode-7f9b7bbd77-pcbfc         1/1     Running            0          3s     app=gethnode,env=dev1,pod-template-hash=7f9b7bbd77
gotty-dev1-59dcb68f45-4mwds       0/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          20d    app=gotty,env=dev1,pod-template-hash=59dcb68f45
```

kubectl get svc gethnode -n mynamespace -o wide

```
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP        EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE   SELECTOR
gethnode   ClusterIP   192.107.220.229   <none>        8550/TCP   64m   app=gethnode,env=dev1
```

Comment: Edit the question to add output of `kubectl get pods -n mynamespace --show-labels`

Comment: thanks @ArghyaSadhu already add the result of the command

Answer (score 2):

Remove `env: dev1` from the selector of the service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gethnode
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    app: gethnode
    env: dev1
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    port: 8550
    targetPort: 8550
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: gethnode
```

Comment: thank for your help, but it still doesn't work.
Selector:          app=gethnode,env=dev1,pod-template-hash=7f9b7bbd77
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                192.103.94.255
Port:              tcp  8550/TCP
TargetPort:        8550/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

Comment: Okay..remove `pod-template-hash: 7f9b7bbd77` and `env: dev1` from the selector of service

Comment: Did it, but I still got the same result. Selector: app=gethnode
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                192.101.79.135
Port:              tcp  8550/TCP
TargetPort:        8550/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>

Comment: Is there any logs? that we can see what happens when applying a service

Comment: Edit the question to add output of `kubectl get svc gethnode -n mynamespace -o wide`

Comment: Did it. I also add env=dev1 back to the selector.

Comment: the problem is with only this deployment? Can you check logs of kube controller manager pod in `kube-system` namespace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220394/discussion-between-pakorn-k-and-arghya-sadhu).

Comment: @PakornK Any progress on this?

Comment: I tried to manually add endpoint to the service and get this error message ".\\endpoint_gotty.yaml": endpoints "gotty" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:mynamespace:myuser" cannot get resource "endpoints" in API group "" in the namespace "mynamespace". It seems like my user doesn't have authorization to view endpoint. that's why I can't see the endpoint of the service. However, I implemented ingress over that service and it worked. thank for your help

Comment: Ingress also needs endpoints to be populated for it to work...can you check the kube controller manager logs..that might give clue why endpoints is not populated

Comment: I don' have an authorization to do that. it works now and i can access the pods via ingress, even if I can't see the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, and what I did was to delete the Deployment, Secrets associated, Service, and Ingress to start fresh. Then make sure that my Deployment is consistent with my service in the naming, specifically talking about `app.kubernetes.io/name` as I used to have just `name` in my deployment and `app.kubernetes.io/name` in my service causing this discrepancy. In any case, now I got endpoints populated:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webhook
  namespace: apps
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: webhook
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: webhook
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: webhook
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webhook
        image: registry.min.dev/minio/webhook:latest
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 23411
        env:
        - name: GH_TOKEN
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: webhooksecret
              key: GH_TOKEN
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-creds
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webhook
  namespace: apps
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: webhook
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 23411
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: webhook
```

And as a result:

```
$ k get ep webhook -n apps
NAME      ENDPOINTS              AGE
webhook   192.168.177.67:23411   4m15s
                 |
                 |___ Got populated!
```